# ifelse not working to update dataframe in loop

Tags: r

I have df:

`meds`

I want to loop through them and change a column where the row contains any part of the given string to just the given string:

```
med_strings <- c('amitriptyline',
'clomipramine',
'codeine',
'desipramine',
'fluvoxamine',
'hydrocodone',
'imipramine',
'trimipramine',
'nortriptyline',
'paroxetine',
'tamoxifen',
'venlafaxine',
'vortioxetine',
'tramadol',
'ondansetron',
'tropisetron')

for (med_string in med_strings) {
  meds$MedicationNameSimple <- ifelse(grepl(med_string, meds$MedicationName, ignore.case = T), med_string, meds$MedicationName)

}
```

However this does not seem to be updating in place, for example

`ONDANSETRON HCL` is not replaced with `ondansetron` etc

Any suggestions?

Here is the head of meds$MedicationName:

```
[1] "ONDANSETRON HCL (PF) 4 MG/2 ML INJECTION SOLUTION"
[2] "ONDANSETRON HCL (PF) 4 MG/2 ML INJECTION SOLUTION"
[3] "ONDANSETRON HCL (PF) 4 MG/2 ML INJECTION SOLUTION"
[4] "venlafaxine (EFFEXOR XR) 150 mg 24 hr capsule"
[5] "ONDANSETRON HCL (PF) 4 MG/2 ML INJECTION SOLUTION"
[6] "HYDROcodone-acetaminophen (NORCO) 7.5-325 mg tablet"
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this without sample data. Please add the output from `dput(head(meds,10))` (or some row-sampling that includes the problematic `ONDANSETRON HCL`).

Comment: curious, is it possible that you have an encoding issue with your original data? It can be problematic when something in a string is subtly non-ascii. Regardless, sample data (using `dput`) would help us find this.

Comment: @r2evans I added some row sampling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With every iteration you are just writing over your previous version. I suspect you output appears to work for 'tropisetron'.

Your replacement needs to be to the same column against you're using for FALSE condition. Otherwise you are just reverting back in the next iteration for each of the meds. If you don't want to lose the original data, initialize `meds$MedicationNameSimple` to the original data before the loop

```
meds$MedicationNameSimple <- meds$MedicationName
for (med_string in med_strings) {
  meds$MedicationNameSimple <- ifelse(grepl(med_string, meds$MedicationNameSimple, ignore.case = T), med_string, meds$MedicationNameSimple)
}
```